# How to implement a PPPoe server?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming, ppp, pppoe

I want to develop one PPPoe-like server, so I can create a virtual connecting among server and client. Is there any opensource project for reference ？ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pppd can do PPPoE (and about a billion other things).  I'm not sure what you mean by "virtual" though.  Both ends of PPPoE connection have to be on the same Ethernet LAN (strictly speaking there are ways around this, but that involves solving the same problem I think you are trying to solve).

I think you may be more interested in a VPN (Virtual Private Network).

Comment: one more question, If one pc has a NAT IP(means the pc hava connected a NAT server), Does it can be connected the PPP server also ?

Comment: @why: PPPoE works at a level below NAT. Any router will block PPPoE.

Comment: Thanks for you good reply. So Any router will not block VPN, if it is right, can you give me a explain

Comment: @Why: Usually when someone says "router" they are referring to an Internet Protocol Router which routes IP packets. PPPoE packets are not IP packets. IP was designed to be encapsulated in many different types of physical networks. PPP and Ethernet are two of the most popular network types that can carry IP. You can also encapsulate PPP on withing Ethernet (PPPoE) and Ethernet over IP (EoIP) and you can encapsulate IP packets within encrypted UPD packets (a type of IP packet) and have a VPN.

Comment: @Why: VPNs generally are slower than Local Area Networks, but you will likely have a similarly slow connection if you use something else because it will be doing mostly the same stuff. You could skip the encryption/decryption and get a little bit of speed but you may not even notice it.

Comment: @why, from what i understood normally your pppoe connection to ISP is after NAT and your LAN side is behind NAT so basically your data is exchanged encapsulated in PPP over Ethernet. The LAN Part is NAT'd but from ISP side your IP inside PPPoE is the same un-Natted one,